# Insert/remove dark theme stylesheet toggle button

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I attempted to make this dark mode switch that inserts a stylesheet in `head` and a local storage on click. It supposed to disable it on every second click, but the problem is that on first click I get the `on` output, but from second click it just keeps outputing `off` forever.

I also would like it to have another condition if the page is already running dark theme, the switch disables the inserted stylesheet and keeps looping like this.

I'm open to have a PHP alternative.

```
$(function() {
    var linkDarkMode;
    $(".dark-theme").click(function() {
        if (!linkDarkMode) {
            linkDarkMode = $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/body/dark-theme.css">').appendTo('head')[0];
            localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
            console.log("on");
        } else {
            linkDarkMode.disabled = !linkDarkMode.disabled;
            localStorage.removeItem("theme");
            console.log("off");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linkDarkMode` will retain the value after first click and hence every subsequent click handler call will go in the `else` block failing the `if` check. Just take another boolean like `isThemeDark` for keeping the status of the current theme and do this

```
$(function() {
    var linkDarkMode;
    var isThemeDark = false;
    $(".dark-theme").click(function() {
        if (!linkDarkMode) {
            linkDarkMode = $(
                '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/body/dark-theme.css">'
            ).appendTo("head")[0];
            localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
            console.log("on");
        } else {
            if (isThemeDark) {
                linkDarkMode.disabled = true;
                localStorage.removeItem("theme");
                console.log("off");
            } else {
                linkDarkMode.disabled = false;
                localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
                console.log("on");
            }
            isThemeDark = !isThemeDark;
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Your example turns dark theme on but won't turn it off. It stuck on the last `else`.

Comment: @SLembas Updated the code. Was missing a statement.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but didn't turn off dark theme after page reload. Just had to set the `isThemeDark = !isThemeDark;` inside the cookie reading function and move all the variables above everything.